# How to pass URL to visualforce page with pagereference method without scattering the url?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, url, conga

below is the apex method through which i am passing a URL string to a button in Visual force Page.

```
public Pagereference Submit(){

  loanId1 = 'a2529000000MIBg';
  String SessionId1 = Userinfo.getSessionID();
  system.debug('here is your SessionId = '+ SessionId1);

  string ServerURL1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host');
  system.debug('here is your ServerURL = '+ ServerURL1);

 HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
 req.setEndpoint('https://composer.congamerge.com/composer8/index.html');
 req.setMethod('GET');

 string Startdate1 = Startdate.format();
 system.debug('Startdate1 = '+ Startdate1);

 string Enddate1 = Enddate.format();
 system.debug('Enddate1 = '+ Enddate1);

 string Organizationid = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
 system.debug('Organizationid = '+ Organizationid);

  String URL = 'https://composer.congamerge.com/composer8/index.html?sessionId='+SessionId1+'&serverUrl='+serverurl1+'/services/Soap/u/37.0/'+Organizationid+'&id='+LoanId1+'&templateid=a1U29000000l0vd&reportid=[trn]00O29000000Oo8o?pv1='+Startdate1+'&pv2='+Enddate1+'&defaultpdf=&ds7=3';
   system.debug('Here is your URL =' + URL);

   Pagereference Pageref = New pagereference(URL);
   pageRef.setRedirect(true);
   system.debug('here is your Pageref ='+ Pageref);

   return Pageref;
}
```

}

the Pagereference method is breaking the URL.
how to pass the URL in correct format as defined in the String URL.
like this **https://composer.congamerge.com/composer8/index.html?  sessionId='+SessionId1+'&serverUrl='+serverurl1+'/services/Soap/u/37.0/'+Organizationid+'&id='+LoanId1+'&templateid=a1U29000000l0vd&reportid=[trn]00O29000000Oo8o?pv1='+Startdate1+'&pv2='+Enddate1+'&defaultpdf=&ds7=3';**

Comment: You problem is that you need to URLEncode the serverURL param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need encode the serverURL parameter

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
public Pagereference Submit(){

  loanId1 = 'a2529000000MIBg';
  String SessionId1 = Userinfo.getSessionID();

  String ServerURL1 = Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();

  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
  req.setEndpoint('https://composer.congamerge.com/composer8/index.html');
  req.setMethod('GET');

  String Startdate1 = Startdate.format();
  system.debug('Startdate1 = '+ Startdate1);

  String Enddate1 = Enddate.format();
  system.debug('Enddate1 = '+ Enddate1);

  String Organizationid = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
  system.debug('Organizationid = '+ Organizationid);


  String salesforceURL = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(ServerURL1+'/services/Soap/u/37.0/'+Organizationid,'UTF-8');

  Pagereference newPage = new pagereference('https://composer.congamerge.com/composer8/index.html');
  newPage.getParameters().put('sessionId',SessionId1);
  newPage.getParameters().put('id',loanId1);
  newPage.getParameters()-put('templateid','a1U29000000l0vd');
  newPage.getParameters()-put('reportid','[trn]00O29000000Oo8o?pv1='+Startdate1+'&pv2='+Enddate1);
  newPage.getParameters()-put('ds7','3');
  newPage.getParameters()-put('defaultpdf','true');
  newPage.getParameters().put('serverUrl',salesforceURL);
  return Pageref;
}
```

Comment: I tried the above approach.but still after the serverurl1 it is not getting session id.sessionid si getting placed at the last.below is the debug log statement.

Comment: |Debug| here is your Pageref = System.Pagereference[https://composer.congamerge.com/composer8/index.html?serverUrl=cimgroup--test.cs19.my.salesforce.com%252Fservices%252FSoap%252Fu%252F37.0%252F00D290000008j9GEAQ%2526id%253Da2529000000MIBg%2526templateid%253Da1U29000000l0gAd%2526reportid%253D%255Btrn%255D00O29000000Oo8o%253Fpv1%253D9%252F1%252F2016%2526pv2%253D9%252F30%252F2016%2526defaultpdf%253D%2526ds7%253D3&sessionId=00D290000008j9G%21AQEAQENMbDJT4yaL.RfWyadUOnWH1SyWUhGaIU5yCeUJ_i0gETFYIexXBQIcEGAWmsElCp2Nwrg7dpta3whK3RShbP_yGdbz]

Comment: @karthik where are you setting the sessionId1??

Comment: string ServerURL1 = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host'); that is incorrect if you are in a visualforce because the visualforce server is xx.visual.force.com not xx.salesforce.com. In 5 sec I send you the correct way to obtain the server

Comment: your serverURL1  should be  Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()

Comment: @ Torsen Thank you Very much for your Help. I will Implement your suggestions and update you.

Comment: @karthik You are welcome. please close the question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending those parameters to URL string, just add it to Parameters Map, like below:

```
pageRef.getParameters().put('sessionId',SessionId1);
```

Also, please note that, for example, you won't see forward slash (`/`) as a part of your URL parameters in the browser, as that character will be encoded to `%2F`. But that's normal, and you should still be able to read those parameters in its original form on the page you navigated to.